# Laptop for programming, app and web developing in US$650

Tags: laptop

I'm looking for a laptop that can sustain app, web developing and programming in different languages. I also play call of duty occasionally.
Basically what I'm looking for is:

- Intel core i5 6200U
- 1TB Hard Disk
- 2GB NVIDIA or AMD Graphics
- 4-8 gb Ram.
- Dell or HP.

My budget is around 660 US$.

Comment: You could use a dell latitude. Those laptops have some pretty decent specs but I do not know about a graphics card. I have a Dell latitude e6420 and I can do some development on it but that is a pretty low end model and since your budget is 660 then you could probably get a laptop that is pretty fast.